# Update Firestore Single Index [0] from 0,1,2,3 indexs of data i

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, indexing

[I want to update specific index of firestore database via javascript i tried alot but there is no way for me :(

[Data View of my products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnY0y.png)

```
    const ref = firestore
    .collection('collections')
    .doc("dsflkjeowjjljsd3Xfkl")
    .items.doc(productIndex);

  ref
    .update(
      {
        [`items.${productIndex}`]: fieldUnion({...objectToUpdate, id: productId}),
      },
      {merge: true}
    ) // sets the contents of the doc using the id
    .then(() => {
      // fetch the doc again and show its data
      ref.get().then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data()); // prints {id: "the unique id"}
      });
    });
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet showing what you've tried and the error(s) you are getting

Comment: Thanks please check now

Comment: When you want to show a screen-grab, please paste the image *here*.  Following a link is both dangerous and inconvenient to *us*.  The easier you make it for us to see your issues, the more likely you are to get answers.

Comment: Sorry but the image uploader i got from stackoverflow so i am unable to show direct images i tried but now working

Comment: There is no way to update a single item in an array with the Firestore API. You will need to update the array in its entirety, typically by: 1) reading the document, 2) getting the entire array from it, 3) updating the item in the array, 4) writing the entire updated array back to the database.